# C string using index or pointer to copy characters

Tags: c, performance, gcc, x86-64, micro-optimization

I have 2 source code for (strcpy) function and i want to know which one is faster and has more performance ...

```
unsigned
strcpy(const char * str, char * des) {
    register const char * ptr = str;

    while ((*des = *str)) {
        str++;
        des++;
    }

    return (str - ptr);
}

unsigned
strcpy2(const char * str, char * des) {
    register unsigned i = 0;

    while ((des[i] = str[i])) i++;

    return i;
}
```

first one using str and des address and second one using index ...
first one has an extra (++) so in first look, it seams that the performance of the first function is less than second one because of doing extra (++) for each character but when i used (-O3) optimization in GCC, the result (Assembly code) tell me something else (that first strcpy has more performance and less action)

```
strcpy:
        movzbl  (%rdi), %eax
        movb    %al, (%rsi)
        testb   %al, %al
        je      .L4
        movq    %rdi, %rax
.L3:
        movzbl  1(%rax), %edx
        addq    $1, %rax
        addq    $1, %rsi
        movb    %dl, (%rsi)
        testb   %dl, %dl
        jne     .L3
        subl    %edi, %eax
        ret
.L4:
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        ret
strcpy2:
        movzbl  (%rdi), %eax
        testb   %al, %al
        movb    %al, (%rsi)
        movl    $0, %eax
        je      .L10
.L9:
        leal    1(%rax), %ecx
        movzbl  (%rdi,%rcx), %edx
        movq    %rcx, %rax
        movb    %dl, (%rsi,%rcx)
        testb   %dl, %dl
        jne     .L9
        ret
.L10:
        ret
```

is it true ? the first strcpy has more performance (perfomance = less action and faster) ?

Comment: The both append a redundant terminated zero.

Comment: I mean that the assignment after the loop is redundant. You may remove it.

Comment: ok but this is not the problem ... but thank you anyway !

Comment: If you want to know which of two valid codes is faster then the first thing to do is ***test*** that for some characteristic inputs.

Comment: @Jason This is not a problem but the code looks like it is written in hurry.

Comment: @Jason, humans are very bad at estimating the performance of a program from its source code (and assembly is source code, too).  Moreover, relative performance may vary depending on the hardware on which the program runs.  Testing is the best and most reliable way to go.

Comment: The 2nd version of the asm has serious missed optimizations (separate from not auto-vectorizing because gcc never does that for search loops).  The lea+mov is obviously worse than just `inc`, which would get it down to 4 fused-domain uops on CPUs other than Sandybridge/Ivybridge where the indexed addressing modes for the store would unlaminate.  [Micro fusion and addressing modes](//stackoverflow.com/q/26046634).  **Obviously these are both horrible, only copying 1 byte at a time, and not even able to manage 1 byte per clock cycle on Intel CPUs.**  SSE2 is baseline for x86-64.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Speak for yourself; I'm pretty sure Intel Haswell and later will run either of these loops at 1.25 cycles per byte for large copies, bottlenecked on the front-end.  It will slow down a small amount for huge copies with page faults and cache misses, but it's slow enough for HW prefetch to easily keep up most of the time.

Answer (score 5):

Never mind. 
Both are probably slower than the strcpy from the Standard library.
The GCC will do good inline code if you don't implement strcpy by yourself.

The perfomance bottle necks in modern CPUs is the Cache and RAM bandwidth not the opcodes.

Comment: No, @Jason, they are not kidding you.

Comment: i can't belive that you saying this !!!!!!!!! even the GCC using function num 1 !!!! https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/memcpy.c .... (what notan said is not useful for this function ... it's for big functions)

Comment: @Jason: That's the generic fallback implementation, or for gcc internal use.  It's not what gcc inlines.  For that, look at compiler *output* with optimization enabled.  (like `-O3 -march=native`).  For compile-time-constant sizes, it will inline `movups` or `movdqu` instructions, or with AVX maybe using `vmovdqu` with 32-byte YMM vector registers.

Comment: For unknown-size, it will use call libc `strcpy` which will use SSE2, SSSE3, or AVX2.  e.g. https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-avx2.S.html.  If you write your own strcpy, it won't autovectorize, and you won't get the benefit of glibc's runtime CPU dispatching to pick an implementation using your CPU's features.  Try compiling optimized code and single-stepping into `strcpy` in a debugger.  (e.g. `gcc -fno-plt -O3 -march=native`).

Comment: Consider: The GCC implementors have been working on their implementation of `strcpy()` (including intrinsics and optimizer support) for *decades*. Why would you expect that your code would outperform theirs?

Comment: @Peter Cordes  i need to read more about what you said ... but there is a question ... some big softwares like nginx, using their own functions (strlen and ...) which are exactly the same as my function ... you telling me that they are wrong?

Comment: @Jason: If they actually use them when the implementation provides an optimized implementation, then yes, I am.  You'd only ever want that as a fallback in case of missing libc functions.  Or possibly if your strings are almost always tiny (like 4 bytes or less) so the cost of a function call is higher than the cost of running a slow byte-at-a-time loop.  See also [Why is this code 6.5x slower with optimizations enabled?](//stackoverflow.com/q/55563598) where gcc inlining a slow `strlen` does really badly for very long strings for a detailed analysis of asm implementations.

Answer (score 3):

The 2nd excerpt is **invalid** for copying a string. You're using 32-bit `unsigned int` on a platform where pointers are 64 bits. Hence the compiler needs to be **very careful** to account for **32-bit modulo arithmetic** in indices. If you change `i` to **`size_t`** as it *should be* then the compiler can eliminate the zero-extensions and `LEA`s.

In any case, your version will always be slower than the compiler version - because in compiler the `strcpy` is an **intrinsic function** - the compiler can know to replace it with **`memcpy`** or even **just loading the individual characters into registers** instead of mindlessly copying some bytes from one part of memory to another.

Comment: It's zero-extension, not sign-extension, so it's free just from writing a 32-bit register.  The LEA+MOV instead of ADD is because of which value the compiler wants to return.  (GCC easily gets fooled into putting extra instructions inside a loop to set up for how it wants registers after the loop, instead of just putting a `mov` after the loop.)

Comment: oops, fixed the zign to sero extension.

Comment: Interesting, turns out you're right and `size_t` does let gcc optimize the LEA/MOV into just ADD.  https://godbolt.org/z/ptwpcM.  clang simplifies the function a lot by using `1(%rsi,%rax)` addressing modes and starting off with `rax=-1`.  The copy is in the loop condition so that always runs at least once; only the increment might need to run zero times but it adjusts for that.

Comment: @PeterCordes what is most strange is that `signed int` didn't look much better than `unsigned` on GCC though, compiler "knew" it needs to return a 32-bit value...

Comment: Even GCC 8 uses lea with `signed int`, only with 64-bit register :D

Comment: Oh interesting.  Yeah that extra `movl    %eax, %r8d` *inside* the loop instead of just `movl    %eax, %eax` after the loop is exactly the kind of GCC stupidity I was talking about.  At least it's off the critical path so it doesn't depend on mov-elimination to avoid bottlenecking at 2 cycles / iter on the loop-counter dep chain.  (I'm looking at gcc9.1 where it uses `add $1, %rax` and a `mov` into `r8d` which is only read *outside* the loop.  https://godbolt.org/z/e2tIrm  GCC8.3 is similar)